Can I put two ContentPage inside a ShellContent?
Briefing:
I've a fixed content (in red) page which will show a progress bar, this content page must be always visible on top of another variable content pages (from ShellContent)
I want to when I select another content page in my FlyoutItem, it only Route the content page to the blue area
I need something like this:

My AppShell code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="Mobile.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Mobile"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Flyout">
    <Shell.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Style="{StaticResource FloutItemStyle}">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Source="{Binding FlyoutIcon}"
                Margin="10"
                HeightRequest="50"
                HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" />
                <Label Grid.Column="1"
                Text="{Binding Title}"
                TextColor="{StaticResource LightTextColor}"
                FontSize="Body"
                VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                x:Name="_label">
                </Label>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Shell.ItemTemplate>



    <FlyoutItem Title="Páginas" FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems" FlyoutIcon="factorpro.png">

        <!-- Page1 -->
        <ShellContent
        Title="Calcular Aditivo"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page1}"
        Route="Page1"
        IsVisible="False"
        Icon="aditivo.png"/>
...
    </FlyoutItem>

</Shell>


You could do that using ContentPages, you don't need to involve shell in the equation, if you want i can add a small example for you

But I've to code every content page in my solution, right?

I don't think i understand your question

Can you show that small example for me? Then I can tell if it's what I need... I tried to be clearest as possible, but I still very new with xamarim/net maui
